# Include C++ Example in a Sphinx/Breathe/Doxygen Documentation

Tags: c++, documentation, python-sphinx, doxygen, restructuredtext

I'm trying to include an example in my C ++ documentation through Sphinx,  Breathe and Doxygen.

It doesn't seem to be easy, because the **@example** statement doesn't work.
And with the **@include** statement, the ***.rst-file** is output as simple text and not as code.

does anyone have an idea how to do something like that?

Comment: The [@example command of Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample) _does_ work. However, it's not quite intuitive (IMHO). You have to place it under the class or function where the example _belongs_ to. (I needed a while to get this...) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
you are right, it works for the Doxygen Documentation but unfortunately not for the Sphinx :(

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Besides the `\example` doxygen has `\include` command maybe this is more what you want. Might be that this is what @Scheff'sCat was pointing at as more an intuitive way to g\have an example. (And with `\par` or `name` etc you could add a sort of caption to it.

Comment: @albert My (wrong) intuition let me think I should remark the sample code with `@example`. Instead, the `@example` has to be used where the sample code is referred in. ;-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.